# Argentina's involvement with the League of Nations

Tags: 20th-century, political-history, diplomacy, argentina

Argentina was a founding member of the League of Nations. However, Argentina left in 1921 when an Argentine resolution was rejected. Why, and through what procedure (if any), was Argentina allowed to **rejoin** the League in 1933?

Comment: I noticed Yugoslavia did the same-- joined, left, and then rejoined.

Comment: @Luke Welcome to History.SE. Do you happen to know the dates Yugoslavia left and rejoined? I am curious of to know, perhaps they followed a similar process as Argentina.

Comment: I noticed it per this map-http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/League_of_Nations_Anachronous_Map.PNG However, I can't seem to find any other information of it. Maybe the map was mistaken.

Comment: @Luke thanks for the map. It is very interesting. The only thing I new about Yugoslavia was that at one point the League was upset with an incident involving its surrounding countries. I wonder if that resulted in them leaving at some point. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not sure. That might be a question in itself. One thing I do know is that the borders of Yugoslavia were drawn roughly over ethnic boundaries in most parts. The trouble might have been ethnic problems within borders that weren't drawn to completely separate ethnicities.

Comment: @Luke I agree with both points. If either you or I can find out enough about the situation to propose a good question I would imagine someone will provide the answer. [Of course we may find the answer within our own research :–)]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3665/discussion-between-luke-and-e1suave)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Argentina had become part of the League by International law, not by it's Constitution. The League turned down several of Argentina's proposed amendments (which contradicted other articles of the League's Covenant) at the first assembly of the League of Nations. Argentina promptly withdrew, but never gave a formal notice of withdrawal.

Argentina, in 1933, under a new president, paid its dues and attended several meetings. This was a simpler process beacuse it was *officially* a suspended or inactive member. Thus, the only things it had to do to rejoin would be to pay its arrears and notify the League of its intent. Paying them off was not very difficult because at the time Argentina was considered a "well-off" nation (it had one of the highest GDP's at the time). I believe it returned mainly because of the new president, Agustín Pedro Justo. He had gained power through the success of a coup. The previous president, Hipólito Yrigoyen, had died the previous year of stomach cancer and the president who had Argentina leave the League of Nations had died earlier that year.

Source: The Origin, Structure & Working of the League of Nations
 By Charles Howard Ellis

Comment: Very well put. I really appreciate the answer. Would you be able to provide a source for how Argentina rejoined. +1 regardless as this is your first answer, and it appears to be a very good one. :–)

Comment: Terrific. Great to have you here at History.SE :–)